# Binding exists but not shown in IIS?

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, bindings

I am working on a powershell script that adds a binding in IIS using New-IISSiteBinding.

After the first run, I keep getting...

```
New-IISSiteBinding : Web site binding '*:443:mydomain.co.uk' already exists.
At line:7 char:1
+ New-IISSiteBinding -Name "MYSITE" -BindingInformation ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-IISSiteBinding], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidArgument,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.NewIISSiteBindingCommand
```

When I call Get-IISSiteBinding, I can see the binding is there.

When I go to ISS, the binding isn't showing against the site.

When I go to applicationHost.config, the binding isn't in the file.

What is happening, please?

Comment: Here's part of some logic I use when renewing SSL certificates but in order I run: `Remove-WebBinding -Name "$SiteName" -IPAddress "*" -Port 443 -Protocol "https";` then I run SSL import logic and then follow that with `New-WebBinding -Name "$SiteName" -IPAddress "*" -Port 443 -Protocol "https";` and then I run other logic and restart IIS. In case any of that helps you, I wanted to share but will be happy to turn into an answer if you tell me. So use `New-WebBinding` instead perhaps and restart your app pool or IIS to see if it then take effect. I think IIS isn't seeing the changes PS makes.

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run an exchange server ? if you are not then try  port 444 - with certificate binding .

443 is default SSL so ,I think that the reason you get that message .

Comment: The issue only started when I ran New-IISSiteBinding. If I remove it using Remove-IISSiteBinding, the issue goes away, until I run it again. Without doubt, the binding has been created by my script.